# Representing a a quantity as a mathematical expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Each parent in a group of 15 parents buys a ticket to a fundraiser show and receives a group discount of $2 off of the regular ticket price.

I need to write an expression that represents the total cost of the tickets in dollars.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Let's let $\;x = \text{regular cost of one ticket, in dollars}.\;$

Now, how much is each ticket discounted at the group rate? $\$2$.

So each *reduced-price* ticket costs $(x - 2)$ dollars.

And we have that $15$ such tickets are purchased: recall $15$ parents bought tickets at the reduced group rate. So we multiply the *reduced ticket* price by $15$!

$$\text{Total cost of tickets}\;  = \;15\times (x - 2)\; = (15x - 30) \;\text{dollars}$$

The unknown "$x$", of course, depends on the original price of a ticket.

Comment: Very clear write-up +1